# Prove a theorem in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that for $k=1,...,(n-1)$ we have :

$\binom{n}{k}\leq \frac{n^n}{k^k(n-k)^{n-k}}$

I have used induction on $k$, but I have not deduced the above relation.

Comment: No. Proof must be for general $n$

Comment: @genisage Yes I know this hint. but you should notice that there is a similar situation in denominator

Comment: Try writing it as $n!k^k(n-k)^{n-k}\leq n^nk!(n-k)!$ and try to find combinatorial interpretations for both sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(k+(n-k))^n \ge \binom nk k^k (n-k)^{n-k}$ because the RHS is one of the terms in the binomial theorem expansion of the LHS.

(This was question B2 on the 2004 Putnam; for some other interesting solutions, see [Kedlaya's archive](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/).)